# Access a member function of an object that is a member variable of a parent class

Tags: php, oop, constructor, parent-child, protected

I'm trying to access a function of an object from a child class, where the object is a protected variable of the parent.

I'm not entirely sure the best way to go about this... any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Below is how I have it setup now, but it's not working. It gives the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to App\Parent::__construct()
>   must be an instance of App\Object, none given, called in
>   Controller.php on line 25 and defined in Parent.php on line 12

So as I understand the error, I need to somehow pass an instance of the Parent class into the Child class. But this seems like an anti-pattern because it's extending the Parent class. I must be missing something basic.

Parent.php

```
class Parent
{
    protected $object;

    public function __construct(Object $object) // line 12
    {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

}
```

Child.php

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        return parent::$object->objectFunction());
    }

}
```

Controller.php

```
...

namespaces etc

...

public function control()
{
    $parent = new Parent(new Object($variable));

    $child = new Child(); // line 25
    $child->doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont instantiate a seperate parent class, it will be instantiated as part of instantiating the child class.

Also pass the object to the child instantiation and create a __construct() method and pass the parameter on to it.

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public __construct($var)
    {
        parent::__construct($var);
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        return parent::$object->objectFunction());
    }

}
```

Controller.php

```
public function control()
{
    //$parent = new Parent(new Object($variable));

    $child = new Child(new Object($variable)); // line 25
    $child->doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense, it's working now! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.